# Java Multiple Producer and Multiple with single queue in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, message-queue, producer-consumer

I have three Producers P1,P2,P3 and Three consumers with single shared queue. Producer P1 will put/insert X1,X2,X3 into queue and it should be consumed only by Consumer C1 not other Consumers(C2,C3). Basically Consumers C1 should only consume values inserted by Producer P1. the same rule applies to rest of the consumers. C2-> P2 and C3->P3.
How to solve this problem in Java.

Comment: Create 3 queues. Why would you use a shared queue, if there is no sharing going on?

Comment: Are you trying to solve it purely with Java using data structures, multi-threading or can you use third party libraries? If yes then I would suggest Kafka and how you can use topic. Basically there is a queue (broker) with n topics with source (producers) and a sink (consumers). Your consumer can subscribe to a particular topic.

Comment: all of them should use/share same queue. and producers insert data randomly into the queue. consumers should take item from respective producers. can we do this in java.

Comment: Yes only with Java and data structures.

Comment: Create a single consumer taking from the queue and distributing to the others after determining data item type.

Comment: What you have there is an esoteric programming puzzle. It's not a "problem" in the normal sense of the word. If your goal is to create reliable, maintainable software that solves some _real-world_ problem, and you think you need two or more threads to pull items from the same queue, then those threads should be completely interchangeable with each other.

Answer (score 0):

The way this would be ultimately working is there would be a class like this

```
class Envelope<S, T, M> {
    final S sender;
    final T topic;
    final M message;
    ...
};
```

All sent messages will be wrapped into it (like real letters in the envelopes)  and posted into a `MailBox`. Dispatcher at the other end of the mailbox will look at topic/receiver fields of the envelope and apply a required policy to deliver to a correct recipient in a correct context (thread).

As to coding it yourself — I would only do it for fun. If I needed something quickly I'd take `Akka` that already has all required primitives and used them.